# How to target div id including all child elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to click a specific div and display a div containing child elements, then when clicking outside of that div and its child elements, the div and its child elements will be set to 'display: none' again. The following code does not work when clicking on child elements of the displayed div, and thus results in hiding the parent div. How do I include all child divs within event.target.id == 'menu-container' in the following code?

```
<body>
  <div id = "screen">
        <div id = "menu-container">
            <li class = "menu-options">
                <ul>option-1</ul>
                <ul>option-2</ul>
                <ul>option-3</ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id = "bottom-panel">
            <div id = "menu-button">
            CLICK HERE FOR MENU
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
 <body>
```

The JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').click(function(event){
    if ( event.target.id == 'menu-button'){
        $("#menu-container").show();
    }else if(event.target.id == 'menu-container'){

        return true;
    }else{
        $('#menu-container').hide();
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ecABg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/ecABg/4/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').click(function(event){
        if ( event.target.id == 'menu-button'){
            $("#menu-container").show();
        } 
        else if (event.target.id == 'menu-container' || 
                    $(event.target).parents('#menu-container').length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            $('#menu-container').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Also you should correct your list, it should be:

```
<ul class="menu-options">
    <li>option-1</li>
    <li>option-2</li>
    <li>option-3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution only works for the children of parent div class="menu-options" and not for all children of div id = "menu-container". You can see this by clicking above the top ul and below the border of #menu-container. Adding .menu-options to children elements is a solution but it isn't the most efficient solution.

Comment: this works for any level of child elements under div#menu-container and allows me to omit class="menu-options". This is the most efficient solution I could hope for.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an boolean to check if your menu id open or not, like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target);
    if (event.target.id == 'menu-button'){
        $("#menu-container").show();
    }else if($(event.target).hasClass("menu")){
        return true;
    }else{
        $('#menu-container').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Also, your HTML code seems incorret to me, i would use:

```
<ul class = "menu-options">
  <li class="menu">option-1</li>
  <li class="menu">option-2</li>
  <li class="menu">option-3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is still does not target the children elements and produces the same result as the code I posted.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the answer. I added a class to each li and now i check if the element has the class added.